# Android Studio Can't Go to Admin Page

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

So I am new to Android Studio and I am trying to make a login page. In my DB I created user_type attribute and if the user type is Admin, I want the login screen to redirect to the Admin Page instead of the normal home page. I tried using if-else statement for the intent, but it still always redirects me to the MainActivity class even though my user_type is already "Admin". Can anyone help tell me the problem? Thanks in advance.

Here is my User class:

```
package com.example.voluminous.model;

//Create User class
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is my DB Open Helper:

```
package com.example.voluminous.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.voluminous.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_TYPE = "user_type";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_USER_TYPE + " TEXT DEFAULT 'Customer' NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";

    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public UserDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user (user_type, user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", new Object[]{"Admin","Administrator","admin@voluminous.com","123"});
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        //Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to create user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_TYPE, user.getType());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user and return the list of user records
     *
     * @return list
     */
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID,
                COLUMN_USER_TYPE,
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD
        };
        // sorting orders
        String sortOrder =
                COLUMN_USER_NAME + " ASC";
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // query the user table
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,    //columns to return
                null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
                null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,       //group the rows
                null,       //filter by row groups
                sortOrder); //The sort order


        // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID))));
                user.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_TYPE)));
                user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL)));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)));
                // Adding user record to list
                userList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return user list
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * This method to update user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_TYPE, user.getType());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // updating row
        db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to delete user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // delete user record by id
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";

        // selection argument
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};

        // query user table with condition
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                      //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my LoginActivity class:

```
package com.example.voluminous;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.autofill.UserData;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.voluminous.model.User;
import com.example.voluminous.sql.UserDatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private UserDatabaseHelper UserDBHelper;
    private Button mBtLoginactivityRegister;
    private RelativeLayout mRlLoginactivityLayout;
    private EditText mEtLoginactivityEmail;
    private EditText mEtLoginactivityPassword;
    private LinearLayout mLlLoginactivityTwo;
    private Button mBtLoginactivityLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        initView();

        UserDBHelper = new UserDatabaseHelper(this);
    }

    private void initView() {

        mBtLoginactivityLogin = findViewById(R.id.bt_loginactivity_login);
        mBtLoginactivityRegister = findViewById(R.id.bt_loginactivity_register);
        mRlLoginactivityLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl_loginactivity_layout);
        mEtLoginactivityEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_loginactivity_email);
        mEtLoginactivityPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_loginactivity_password);
        mLlLoginactivityTwo = findViewById(R.id.loginactivity_loginbox);

        mBtLoginactivityLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtLoginactivityRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.tv_loginactivity_register:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.bt_loginactivity_login:
                String email = mEtLoginactivityEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mEtLoginactivityPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    ArrayList<User> data = (ArrayList<User>) UserDBHelper.getAllUser();
                    boolean match = false;
                    boolean isAdmin = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        User user = data.get(i);
                        if (email.equals(user.getEmail()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                            if (user.getType().equals("Admin"))
                                isAdmin = true;
                            match = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            match = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (match) {
                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                        editor.putString("e-mail", email);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (!isAdmin)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if (isAdmin)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdminActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect user name or password, please re-enter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your user name or password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you should use Room for your local database SQLite operations,  Room makes your database operations very easy

Comment: put some logs (`Log.i()`) into code and verify that user have `type` equals `"Admin"` and flag is properly set. also I highly recommend using [`Android-Debug-Database`](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) - using this tool you will be able to verify what exists in your database

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me to log. I figured the problem is with my admin creation in the database helper.  It listed type as Administrator instead of Admin, so this is a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 0):

in your LoginActivity

remove the following line from the for loop

```
 else { match = false;}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
User user = data.get(i);
if (email.equals(user.getEmail()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                            if (user.getType().equals("Admin"))
                                isAdmin = true;
                            match = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

if your email and password got a match then u set match =true. but then the loop gonna keep continue to the next checking where its gonna set match=false. u don't need an else condition if u are just trying to find a match using for loop. when u get a match u should stop the loop in this case remove the else condition where u set match=false

Comment: This is a bug but not the problem in question. If match is false, neither Activity will open.

Comment: if the match is false then it will show "Incorrect Username and Password", isn't that is supposed to do?

Comment: yes it will show "Incorrect Username..." but will not show MainActivity. Problem is it always show MainActivity.

Comment: now I understand what u said earlier, if the match is false, it won't open any activity, but in question he says, it always opens MainActivity, that only happens if the match is true and isAdmin=false, but still, I don't see the point of setting match =false in the loop, because the match will become false, if the last element of the array doesn't match the checking, that's why I mentioned that in the answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't realize the problem, but I removed it now.  I also just noticed the problem was on my end when creating the admin user, I listed the type as "Administrator" instead of "Admin".

Comment: oh okay, I'm glad that it solved now,  that's why u should always consider using Log or Debugger to make sure the conditions are done right :)

Answer (score -1):

Well this need a debug. I suggest add several lines so you see information in LogCat.

```
                        if (user.getType().equals("Admin"))
                            isAdmin = true;
                        else
                            Log.i("Match", user.getName() + " has type " +  user.getType() + " is not Admin");
```

If you still have problem,  paste your LogCat to show us here.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me diagnose the problem.